# Python pandas combine the second row if the first row IDs are the same

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

We are using Python 2.7

We have a simple table below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo polar bear'.split(),
               'B': '1 1 2 3 2 2 1 3 4 5'.split()})
print(df)
```

It generates

```
       A  B
0    foo  1
1    bar  1
2    foo  2
3    bar  3
4    foo  2
5    bar  2
6    foo  1
7    foo  3
```

Is there any Pandas way to match the `ID` in the column `A`?  For example, if the `ID` in the column `A` is the same, then concatenate the second row into a dictionary or a list.  For example:

```
{'foo,12213','bar,132'}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is a little vague -- you mention dictionaries and lists, and then give a set containing strings -- but if you just care about the matched information and not the format it's in, then IIUC, you could use `groupby`.  If B consists of strings (as it does in your example frame), it's easy:

```
>>> df.groupby("A")["B"].sum()
A
bar        132
bear         5
foo      12213
polar        4
Name: B, dtype: object
>>> dict(df.groupby("A")["B"].sum())
{'polar': '4', 'bar': '132', 'foo': '12213', 'bear': '5'}
```

If B is made up of integers instead, we'd have to convert them to strings, maybe using something like

```
>>> df["B"].astype(str).groupby(df["A"]).sum()
A
bar        132
bear         5
foo      12213
polar        4
Name: B, dtype: object
>>> dict(df["B"].astype(str).groupby(df["A"]).sum())
{'polar': '4', 'bar': '132', 'foo': '12213', 'bear': '5'}
```

I recommend reading the documentation on the [split-apply-combine pattern](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: After your answer I just realized sum concatenates strings :)

Answer (score 1):

You could groupby aggregate to list and join the list as below.

```
df
Out[7]: 
     A  B
0  foo  1
1  bar  1
2  foo  2
3  bar  3
4  foo  2
5  bar  2
6  foo  1
7  foo  3

df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(list)
Out[10]: 
A
bar          [1, 3, 2]
foo    [1, 2, 2, 1, 3]

new_df = df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(list).reset_index()

new_df['B'] = new_df['B'].map(lambda x: ''.join([str(i) for i in x]))

     A      B
0  bar    132
1  foo  12213

new_df.set_index("A").to_dict()
Out[34]: {'B': {'bar': '132', 'foo': '12213'}}
```